# Remove white border from dots in a seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, layout, seaborn

The [scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) from seaborn produces dots with a small white boarder. This is helpful if there are a few overlapping dots, but it becomes visually noisy once there are many overlaying dots. How can the white borders be removed?

```py
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
```

[image: A seaborn scatterplot of the tips dataset.]

Comment: `ax = sns.scatterplot(..., color='b', edgecolor='b')`. You can also try `... edgecolor='none')`, but then you won't get antialiased circles, so they'd look a bit less smooth.
`

Comment: by my understanding, if using edgecolor parameter, it's easier to use edgecolor = 'face' (as in item face color), as if there's a need to change color, you don't need to change edgecolor parameter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of edgecolors use `linewidth = 0`:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, linewidth=0)
```

Comment: The reason to accept this answer is because I like the fact that the colored dots do not visually increase their size to the outer bounds of the edge line. So to wrap up `linewidth=0` leaves the white padding away and `edgecolor=None` apparently replaces the edge color with the color of the dot. Depending on the reader's need the the `edgecolor=None` might be favorable.

Comment: @fabianegli Note that you need `edgecolor='none'` to leave out the edge. Without the quotes `edgecolor=None` means: "take the default color (equal to the face color)". Without the edge, the dots look less smooth, so you might want to choose a narrow line width together with a smaller dot size to compensate the slightly increased visual size.

Answer (score 6):

If you check [searbon documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html), it accepts matplotlib keywords (listed kwargs in seaborn functions' documentaion), therefore, you can either pass, as sugested by @Allan Bruno `edgecolor = 'none'`, `edgecolor = None` (singular, not 'edgecolors'), or `linewidth = 0`

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try passing the argument `edgecolor='none'` or `edgecolor=None` into `sns.scatterplot()`

Comment: `edgecolor` works for me but `edgecolors` does not, funnily enough